# how can I implement "by" function in parallel, or preferably by sparkR

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, apache-spark, sparkr

I need to apply "by" function on a very big data set. The data looks like:

```
id    value1   value2
1      245      446
1      592      567
1      356      642
...    ...
2      231      421
2      423      425
2      421      542
```

I need to calculate something between value1 and value2 for each id, so that:

```
by(dataset, id, function(input) myfun(input$value1, input$value2)
```

However, the data is very very big. Such computation requires a lot of time.

I would like to know, is there anyway to speed up this function.

I want to use parallel method, preferably using sparkR. But I don't know how to get this done. Can SparkR support it?

Comment: Perhaps you can try with `data.table` `library(data.table); setDT(dataset)[, myfun(value1, value2), id]`

Comment: Could you be more precise than _very very big_?

Comment: it is about several hundreds Gigabyte

Comment: You could split up your data by id and parallelize your function across multiple cores with mclapply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short there is no supported of translating `by` / `tapply` with an arbitrary function to SparkR. At this moment (Spark 1.5 / 1.6 Preview) SparkR exposes only a limited subset of Spark SQL API which is more or less a distribute SQL query engine.

I function you want to use can be expressed without R using standard SQL logic with `GROUP BY` and / or window functions then you're good to go.

Some people tend to use internal RDD API which provides operations like `aggregateByKey` / `combineByKey`, `reduceByKey` or `groupByKey`. Personally I would strongly advise against that. This part of the API is much less mature compared to its Scala or Python counterparts, lacks some basic features and is significantly slower.

While software recommendations are off-topic for SO there multiple R libraries you may find useful including `parallel`, [`snow`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/index.html), [`doMC`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/index.html), [`Rmpi`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpi/index.html) and brand fresh [`multidplyr`](https://github.com/hadley/multidplyr). Including great storage options like `data.table` or `ff` and R independent solutions like [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) you have plenty of options. Since problem you're trying to solve is [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) using some combination of these tools should give much higher ROI than tinkering with SparkR internals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If Spark doesn't support R in this way, does it support Scala or Python, to use custom function in parallel? My function is complicated, and can not be expressed in SQL.

Comment: Yes it does. Details depend on a language,  API (DataFrame, RDD) and the function (optimally you want function that is both associative and commutative).